# Allowance failed when attempting to transfer LINK tokens

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm creating a smart contract where users can create NFT raffles. I will be using Chainlink VRF for getting provably fair results. For this, the user who creates the raffle needs to supply the contract with LINK tokens. I'm attempting to transfer these tokens using an allowance.

```
  function initRaffle(address _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _ticketPrice) external {
      require(_ticketPrice > 0, "Ticket price must be bigger than 0");
      require(LINKToken.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= ChainlinkFee, "Insufficient LINK supplied");
      require(LINKToken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= ChainlinkFee, "Allowance failed");
```

Running `initRaffle` results in `Allowance failed`. I've checked and the `LINKToken.balanceOf(msg.sender)` is bigger than the fee, so that shouldn't be the problem. The `LINKToken.balanceOf(address(this))` is 0.

What's going wrong? And how do I create a working function for having the user transfer (fee amount) link tokens to the contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user needs to invoke `approve(yourContractAddress, feeAmount)` directly on the `LINKToken` contract (not through your contract). This sets the `allowance`.

You can then use `transferFrom()` to pull tokens (up to the allowed amount) from the user's wallet.

```
bool success = LINKToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), ChainlinkFee);
```

Comment: Ah I see, how do I create the `approve()` call to the token's contract?

Comment: @root There are several ways. Most common is with a frontend web application, you can use `ethers` or `web3` JS packages connected to MetaMask or other browser extension wallet to build a transaction (to the `LINKToken` address, containing `data` field that executes the `approve()` function) and request the user's wallet to sign&broadcast it. Docs: [Connect to wallet](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--connecting), [Send transaction](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this directly in remix? I have no frontend set up yet and I'm trying to test out my contracts first. I've tried putting `LINKToken.approve(msg.sender, (0.1 * 10 ** 18));` before the `require` statements but that didn't work. @petr

Comment: @root Assuming your Remix IDE is connected to a public network, select the LINKToken contract in the "contract" box, and pass its address to the "At Address" input. This will allow you to interact with the LINK token from the IDE.